# How to transfer executable made of Qt 4.8.3 and OpenCV 2.4.3 from Ubuntu 12.10 to Fedora 14?

Tags: opencv, qt4, fedora, static-linking, ubuntu-12.10

I compiled a Qt-GUI project using Qt 4.8.3 & OpenCv 2.4.3 in Ubuntu 12.10. I need to transfer the executable to Fedora 14 to run. But, for the 1st time, it gave me an error can't open the file & asked me to install pypar2. I don't know what it is so I just installed it & it no longer gives me any error. However, there is no response at all when I double-click the executable.

Before I did all these, I installed the runtime libraries of Qt(qt-devel-4.7.4-7.fc14.i686 & qt-x11-4.7.4-7.fc14.i686) and OpenCV(opencv-devel-2.1.0-6.fc14.i686) in fedora 14, but the version seems not match with my version in Ubuntu.

I also tried to build the dependencies of the project and save them in a folder together with the project's release folder which contains the executable, which I think it's kind of dynamic linking, and no responses as well. I looked through some of the static linking solutions but not sure of them, as I am wondering will it affect my original configurations in Ubuntu.

Can anyone please show me the steps or solutions on how to run the Ubuntu compiled executable in Fedora 14? Thanks.